# Filter empty arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have `arr1` and `arr2` setup like the following.

```
var arr1 = [
    {
      items: ['1','2','3']
    },

    {
      items: ['4','5','6']
    },

    {
      items: [] // empty array
    },

    ...
]

var arr2 = [
    ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    ['D', 'E', 'F'],
    ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
    ...
]
```

What I would like to do is if there is an empty `items` array in `arr1` to:

1. Create a new `filtered_arr` that contains only the objects that have a non-empty `items` array.
2. Figure out the index of that array (in the example above, the empty array occurs in the `arr1[2]` spot) and filter out the corresponding position in `arr2` - meaning removing the `arr2[2]` array

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the native JS array [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter the values in `arr1` by a specified criterion (in this case—whether the value contains a blank array). You can use the [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method to subsequently remove the item at the corresponding index from `arr2` if your criterion is matched.

An implementation of this would look like:

```
var filtered_arr = arr1.filter(function(val, idx) {
    if (val['items'].length == 0) {
        arr2.splice(idx, 1);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/g4rt4Ld6/)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```js
var arr1 = [{
    items: ['1', '2', '3']
}, {
    items: ['4', '5', '6']
}, {
    items: [] // empty array
}, {
    items: ['7', '8', '9']
}, {
    items: ['10', '11', '12']
}]

var arr2 = [
    ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    ['D', 'E', 'F'],
    ['G', 'H', 'I'],
    ['J', 'K', 'L'],
    ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
]

var filtered_arr = [];
arr1.forEach(function(val, idx){
    if(val.items.length){
        filtered_arr.push(val);
    }else{
        arr2.splice(idx, 1)
    }
});

$('#filtered_arr').text(JSON.stringify(filtered_arr));
$('#arr2').text(JSON.stringify(arr2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Filtered Array: <span id="filtered_arr"></span><br />
Array 2: <span id="arr2"></span><br />
```